# calling a function to save data onDestroy() unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this `List<int> RecordedHR = new List<int>;` getting updated in `FixedUpdate()` I want to send it to another script that will calculate it's average and save that said average on my Firebase Realtime data base.

```
public List<int> RecordedHR = new List<int>();

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        LIVEHRDATA.text = FirebaseManager.instance.GetLiveHR();
        str = FirebaseManager.instance.GetLiveHR();

        RecordedHR.Add(str);

        if (str.Equals("Normal"))
        {
            punish = false;

            count = 0;

        }else if (str.Equals("High"))
        {
            count++;
            Debug.Log("Count: "+count);
             
        }

        if(count >= 500 && count<750)
        {
            punish = true;
            Debug.Log("PUNISH FLAG VALUE: " + punish);
            
        }

        if(count >= 750)
        {
            punish = false;
            Debug.Log("PUNISH FLAG VALUE: " + punish);
            AutoPause();
            
        }

        
    }
```

so I'm getting the data in realtime during the scene and I want to send it as soon as the scene is switched, can I do it onDestroy() ?

Comment: Don't use FixedUpdate - its mainly used for physics calculation, use Update instead

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! but could I use on destroy to send the list after it's filled?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly in `c#` ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but depends.
OnDestroy is called as name suggests when object is destroyed, but it is not always the case when you load new scene. Several examples of what can go wrong:

1. When you mark game object as `DontDestroyOnLoad` it will be moved to special separate scene, so it will not be destroyed when original scene is unloaded.
2. Next scene can be loadeed additively and this is not equal to swapping scenes
3. When scene is destroyed, currently there is no guaranted order of destruction, so if your script uses reference to other gameobject or component, it might be "destroyed" already - C# side will exist, but internal C++ side destroyed and it might cause errors.

If you need alternative way to handle this is, then you can use scene loading api `LoadSceneAsync()` and react to load from async operation or you can create some firebase manager script and subscribe to `sceneLoaded` or `sceneUnloaded` [event](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html).
Remember scene load can't handle application quit case.